# Normal distribution tables - right or left?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Are the probabilities in normal distribution tables given typically to the right or left of the $Z$ score?

One such text I am reading says to the right.

However, in my lecturer's exercises, I encountered a problem asking:

If $X \sim N(1,2) $ find $P(X>0)$.

Since $Z \sim \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ then we have

$P(X>0) = P(\frac{X-1}{\sqrt{2}} > \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}) = P(Z > \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}})$

= $1 - \Phi(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$

Now, if it's to the right, and we want to find $P(Z > \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}})$

Don't we just need to look up $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ in our table? Why would we minus it by one? The table gives us the values to the right of $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}$ already.

Comment: Your table should say whether it gives "left" or "right" or from $0$ to $z$ (the other popular choice).  If it doesn't, it's easy to check.  Just see what it gives for large $z$.

Comment: Also note that, to save space, tables often only give values for $z \ge 0$.  You rely on symmetry to handle $z < 0$.  If $-1/\sqrt{2}$ is not in the table, you use $P(Z > -1/\sqrt{2}) = P(Z < 1/\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: thanks robert, your second comment made me realise my error in thinking!

so there generally isn't a standard as to whether tables are 'left' or 'right'?

Comment: There are three different "standards".  See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table